# The argument type 'Query<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error: The argument type 'Query<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'. I'm fairly new to Flutter, and I'm trying to update some code to the latest Flutter/Dart and plugins. It looks like it's happening during the usersQuery, and all the documentation is somewhat esoteric to me, unfortunately(granted, if its anything like last time, I'll sleep a couple of days and then end up smacking myself in the forehead because it was something simple I just happened to miss).  Any help would be appreciated. The error is on :    final allUsers = await geo
.collection(collectionRef: usersQuery)

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dating_app/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:dating_app/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';

class UsersApi {
  /// Get firestore instance
  ///
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  /// Get all users
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> getUsers({
    required List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> dislikedUsers,
  }) async {
    /// Build Users query
    Query usersQuery = _firestore
        .collection(C_USERS)
        .where(USER_STATUS, isEqualTo: 'active')
        .where(USER_LEVEL, isEqualTo: 'user');

    // Filter the User Gender
    usersQuery = UserModel().filterUserLooking(usersQuery);

    // Instance of Geoflutterfire
    final Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();

    /// Get user settings
    final Map<String, dynamic>? settings = UserModel().user.userSettings;

    // // Get user geo center
    final GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(
        latitude: UserModel().user.userGeoPoint.latitude,
        longitude: UserModel().user.userGeoPoint.longitude);

    final allUsers = await geo
        .collection(collectionRef: usersQuery)
        .within(
            center: center,
            radius: settings![USER_MAX_DISTANCE].toDouble(),
            field: USER_GEO_POINT,
            strictMode: true)
        .first;
```

Comment: is there any specific line of code which is giving you this error?

Comment: The error is on the
  "  final allUsers = await geo
            .collection(collectionRef: usersQuery) "
segment of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this :
```

---

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dating_app/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:dating_app/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';

class UsersApi {
  /// Get firestore instance
  ///
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  /// Get all users
  Future<List<dynamic> getUsers({
    required List<dynamic> dislikedUsers,
  }) async {
    /// Build Users query
    Query usersQuery = _firestore
        .collection(C_USERS)
        .where(USER_STATUS, isEqualTo: 'active')
        .where(USER_LEVEL, isEqualTo: 'user');

    // Filter the User Gender
    usersQuery = UserModel().filterUserLooking(usersQuery);

    // Instance of Geoflutterfire
    final Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();

    /// Get user settings
    var settings = UserModel().user.userSettings;

    // // Get user geo center
    final GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(
        latitude: UserModel().user.userGeoPoint.latitude,
        longitude: UserModel().user.userGeoPoint.longitude);

    final allUsers = await geo
        .collection(collectionRef: usersQuery)
        .within(
            center: center,
            radius: settings![USER_MAX_DISTANCE].toDouble(),
            field: USER_GEO_POINT,
            strictMode: true)
        .first;
```

---

Hope this will work

Comment: Didn't work :/ Same error. Looks like it doesn't like something at the "final allUsers" variable.